# How edit a NSString that contains a NSMutableDictionary key/value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary

I have a `NSDictionary` and make a copy of `NSDictionary`:

```
NSDictionary *immutableDict = (NSDictionary *)json;
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [immutableDict mutableCopy];
```

I want to convert this into a `NSString` selection category for then edit contain.

```
NSString * name = [mutableDict objectForKey:@"category"];
name = [name stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mytexttoadd"]];
```

But when I want to change this `NSString` my app crash because the `NSString` is a `NSCFArray` ..

How can make this a `NSString` so I can edit it?

Comment: So you're putting an `NSArray` into the dictionary under the key `category`; you then want to convert that array into a string? What is in the array, what format do you want the string in, and what have you already tried?

Comment: In my array I obtain text in format ( { key:value, ... } ). I'm trying convert this to NSString with: [mutableDict objectForKey:@"category" ] description]; but new line (/n) show in the conversion... I don't want that this character is showing.

Comment: Confusing question. You need something like this? `NSMutableString * string = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[dictionary description]];`

Comment: Yes!, I don't knew how obtain the string for add text. With description I can make this directly in dictionary. Thanks!!

Comment: But the problem is that when I try insert this NSString with the changes into de First NSDictionary, the symbols of new lines (/n) appear too..

Comment: `description` is for debugging. It does not guarantee any particular string. It does not guarantee the same string between versions of the OS. Do not use it for whatever hack you're using it for.

Comment: Then.. How can I do that I want?

Comment: Basically `[json objectForKey:@"category"]` is returning an instance of `NSArray` not `NSString`. Since `NSArray` doesn't respond to `stringByAppendingString` it's throwing a wobbler. You need to check the object types coming from the JSON.

Comment: it is returning an instance of NSDictionary that contains NSArray, for this reason I'm transforming this to NSString to change text, and then reconvert this to Instance NSArray/NSDictionary But this transforming is bad, because appear /n, /" ...